# Coffeescript Putting Spaces around hyphens

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Why is coffeescript reformatting hyphens in my code?

From

```
$('#dropdown-' + e.target.data-service).prepend( "<a href=''>Test</a>" )
```

To

```
return $('#dropdown-' + e.target.data - service).prepend("<a href=''>Test</a>");
```

Comment: @JedSchneider: No; that's a DOM element.

Answer (score 3):

Identifiers cannot have hyphens.
Your code subtracts `service` from `e.target.data`.

You want `e.target['data-service']`.

Or, better yet, use `dataset`: `e.target.dataset.service`.

Comment: Better yet probably `e.target.getAttribute('data-service')`